# re-position react-rnd elements with a css transition

Tags: reactjs, draggable

I have a list of two elements `scenes` rendered as `<Rnd />` components from `"react-rnd"`. What I'd like to happen is when I drag one element close to another one they should swap positions, in the list and in the UI. so `[first, second]` becomes `[second, first]`. The `<Rnd />` position is controlled, this is the code I'm using:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Rnd, Position, DraggableData } from "react-rnd";

interface IScene {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  position: Position;
}

function Scene({
  scene,
  activeScene,
  setActiveScene,
  onDrag
}: {
  scene: IScene;
  activeScene: string;
  setActiveScene: (id: string) => void;
  onDrag: (d: DraggableData) => void;
}) {
  const [dragged, setDragged] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Rnd
      default={{
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: "200px",
        height: "100px"
      }}
      position={scene.position}
      onDragStart={() => setDragged(true)}
      onDragStop={() => setDragged(false)}
      onDrag={(_, d) => onDrag(d)}
      onMouseDown={() => setActiveScene(scene.id)}
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "gray",
        transition: dragged ? "" : "transform 0.5s",
        border: "1px solid",
        borderColor: activeScene === scene.id ? "white" : "gray",
        zIndex: activeScene === scene.id ? "1" : "0"
      }}
    >
      {scene.name}
    </Rnd>
  );
}

const initialScenesState = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "first",
    position: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    }
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "second",
    position: {
      x: 200,
      y: 0
    }
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [scenes, setScenes] = useState<IScene[]>(initialScenesState);
  const [activeScene, setActiveScene] = useState<string>("");

  const handleStackScenes = () => {
    setScenes((scenes) => {
      let currentPosition = 0;
      return scenes.map((scene) => {
        const result = {
          ...scene,
          position: {
            x: currentPosition,
            y: 0
          }
        };
        currentPosition += 200;
        return result;
      });
    });
  };

  const swapScenes = (first: IScene, second: IScene) => {
    setScenes((scenes) => {
      return scenes.map((scene) => {
        if (scene.id === first.id) {
          return second;
        } else if (scene.id === second.id) {
          return first;
        } else return scene;
      });
    });
    handleStackScenes();
  };

  const handleDrag = (scene: IScene) => (d: DraggableData) => {
    console.log(d.x);
    for (let i = 0; i < scenes.length; i++) {
      if (
        Math.abs(scenes[i].position.x - d.x) < 30 &&
        scenes[i].id !== scene.id
      ) {
        swapScenes(scene, scenes[i]);
      }
    }
  };

  console.log(scenes);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {scenes.map((scene) => (
        <Scene
          key={scene.id}
          scene={scene}
          activeScene={activeScene}
          setActiveScene={setActiveScene}
          onDrag={handleDrag(scene)}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem that I'm facing with my code, is that when I drag the left element to the right one, the swap happens exactly how I wanted, in the other way around the swap happens but I don't see a transition effect, when I checked what happens on the console, it seems that on the second case, the dom elements don't swap, but just the content and it the first case the actual dom elements move. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-kalam-lh0fs7?file=/src/App.tsx:0-2815)